# javascript inside a modal

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, dropzone.js

I am trying to write some prototype for myself, i want the code of the modal dynamically load into div on or after the button click, after i done this, the modal shown but cannot activate javascript inside it, can anybody figure out what just happened? 

(single-page just work fine, it only happened when i trying to load those code dynamically) 
(Testing on Firefox)

index.html

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>
  <script src="js/import.js"></script>

 </head>

 <body>

  <div class="container">
   <div class="row text-center">
    <h3>Basic Drag and Drop</h3>
    <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicDropzone" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" 
    url="view/Dropzone.html">Click to Open Dropzone</button>
   </div>

   <div id="Modal"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

import.js

```js
var import_list = [ 
 "https://rawgit.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.js",
 "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js",
 "js/modal.js"
]

for (url of import_list) {
 var js = document.createElement("script");
 js.src = url;
 document.head.appendChild(js);

}



var import_list2 = [
 "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css",
 "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-modal/2.2.6/css/bootstrap-modal.css",
 "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/basic.css",
 "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/min/dropzone.min.css"
]

for (url of import_list2) {
 var ln  = document.createElement("link");
 ln.href = url;
 ln.rel ="stylesheet";
 document.head.appendChild(ln);
}
```

Dropzone.html

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="basicDropzone" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicDropzone" aria-hidden="false">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">

   <div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
    <h4>Basic Dropzone</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <form action="/upload-target" class="dropzone"  >
    </form>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-default">Save Changes</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

This import.js is used to load different lib into the page when first load
after that if the user click the button, modal.html load into #Modal div, and display the modal, an dropzone appeared inside the modal, but it seems not happened to me.

Please feel free to ask if any question on the code.

Comment: even though it is valid, my browser would not recognize for---of loops and I had to change them to regular loops

Comment: you are right, i think that would be better for using regular loops